# SAS code (Change from Baseline time Point)

Tags: sas

In a clinical trial, Systolic and diastolic blood pressure are measured pre-dose (0 hr) and at 1,2,4,8 hour post- dose.

Twelve subjects were studied. The SAS dataset has the following structure

Variable-Vol        Length - 8      Label- Subject  Number
Variable- Ntime       Length- 8       Label   Nominal time post-dose (hours)
Variable- Sups        Length- 8       Label-  Supine Systolic BP (mmHg)

What SAS code could I use to calculate the change from baseline (Oh) at each time point, and then calculate the mean, minimum, maximum change from baseline for the 12 subjects? Edit: This is what I've tried so far

```
   data postbase;

 do until (last.vol);
 *** Only keep pre-dose values;
 set save.vitals (where=(not(ntime <= 0 )));
 by Vol Ntime;
 if Ntime <= 0 then bl = Sups;
 else do;
 chgbl = Sups - bl;
 output;
 end;
 end;
 run;
```

Comment: Unfortunatley that's not the purpose of SO, if you want just advice, post on SAS communities.

Comment: You're using a DoW loop, is that intentional and the level of programming you're at or are you a beginner? DoW loops are complex and even though I'm a 15 year programmer with SAS I still avoid them. You're free to use them of course, just not something I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data postbase;
set save.vitals;
by subject time volume;
retain baseline;
if time=0 then baseline=volume;
else change = volume - baseline;
run;
```

I think your code is too complex by far and I couldn't parse your variable names so just made them up.

I set baseline volume whenever time = 0 and then do the change every other time. 
RETAIN causes the value to stay until it's reset. If you have times that may not be 0 or missing baseline then you may need to modify the query.